# How to disable ALPN extension?

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl, alpn

As per [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN.html), in libcurl, the `CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN` option is enabled by default. For a project, I am trying to disable the ALPN extension, as below:

```
CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
res = curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN, 0L);
if(res == CURLE_OK){
    cout<<"Set CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN to 0L res = "<<res;
}else{
    cout<<"Set CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN to 1L  res = "<<res<<"\t"<<curl_easy_strerror(res);
}
```

This is throwing me an error:

```
Set CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN to 1L  res = 48   An unknown option was passed in to libcurl
```

And, I can see ALPN extension present in TLS handshake, able to see it with Wireshark. How do I disable the ALPN extension?
**Openssl Version: OpenSSL 1.1.0k
Curl Version: 7.67.0**

Comment: Can you verify that your application is linking to a modern enough version of curl? Maybe it is picking up an older version somewhere.

Comment: @Botje, mentioned curl version in the post is got directly from the library by using curl API, `curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW)`, also used `ldd` command to verify the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if you don't compile with libcurl with HTTP2 support (libnghttp2), it is treating `CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN` and `CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN` as unknown options, though ALPN and NPN  are independent of HTTP2. It was a bug in libcurl. 
I had reported this behavior at libcurl github repo [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4668), which they fixed it and fix will be available in next release.

Answer (score 1):

In libcurl, all possible options are `#define`'d in the header, but it doesn't mean all are supported.

It looks like your `libcurl` was not built with HTTP2 support (libnghttp2).

For ALPN or NPN to actually work, [`curl_version_info()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_version_info.html) should include `CURL_VERSION_HTTP2`.

Comment: ALPN and NPN are used independent of
HTTP2.
https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/4672